# ShareKit SHKActionSheet Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sharekit

I whant to use Sharekit in my app, here is the code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com"];
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit"];


SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
[SHK setRootViewController:self.navigationController];

[actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
[actionSheet release];
```

But my app keep crashing on

```
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
```

Why? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Remove this line from your code and try again. 
[SHK setRootViewController:self.navigationController];

Comment: can u xplain more...!!! y are u using Navigation controller

Comment: Still not working even removing that line, pretty sure that the error is here SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of your problem?

Comment: yep it was a silly issue: to use sharekit you got to be signed to the facebook developer program